# Terminal: list subdirectories containing a specific directory name

Tags: command-line, directory

I am trying to write a command that will list all directories in `/usr/share/icons` that contain a folder named "places," but *only* in the first subdirectory.

To make things clearer, there are a lot of icon themes that will be as follows:

```
/usr/share/icons/theme/places
```

There are also a lot of directories that are just for universal icons and are as follows:

```
/usr/share/icons/theme2/32x32/places
```

I only want to list the directories from the first scenario.

UPDATE: When I say I need it to list the directories in /usr/share/icons, I mean that I need the output to contain just the folder names themselves. Meaning, I think that awk or sed will be necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean by "first subdirectory"? The two scenarios you mention appear to hve the same depth. Did you mean the second one to be `/usr/share/icons/theme/32x32/places`?

Comment: Ah, you guys are right, my apologies. I have updated the question to reflect this. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit

It's sufficient to use `bash`'s glob star. This will match all directories inside `/usr/share/icons/` that also have `places` subdirectory within them.

```
$ ls -d /usr/share/icons/*/places                                  
/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/places/
/usr/share/icons/breeze/places/
/usr/share/icons/Deepin-2013/places/
/usr/share/icons/Deepin-icons/places/
/usr/share/icons/Deepin/places/
/usr/share/icons/Deepin-sapphire/places/
/usr/share/icons/Faenza-Dark/places/
```

#### Original answer

The `find` command typically does what one needs when it comes to searching for files or directories. The command bellow will recursively descend into all directories under `/usr/share/icons` and list all directories that have `places` in their name.

```
find /usr/share/icons -type d -iname "*places*"
```

Sample output

```
$ find /usr/share/icons -type d -iname "*places*" | head -n 5                  
/usr/share/icons/Numix-Light/scalable/places
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/places
/usr/share/icons/Deepin-2013/places
/usr/share/icons/Human/48x48/places
```

**EDIT**

`-printf "%h\n"` allows finding the directory path under which a filename was found ; `awk` with field separator of `/` allows printing the last ( `$NF` ) item.

```
================
xieerqi:
$ find /usr/share/icons -maxdepth 2 -type d -iname "*places*"  -printf "%h\n"  
/usr/share/icons/Humanity
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light
/usr/share/icons/Deepin-2013
/usr/share/icons/Faenza-Dark
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
/usr/share/icons/Deepin-icons
/usr/share/icons/Deepin-sapphire
/usr/share/icons/Deepin
/usr/share/icons/Humanity-Dark
/usr/share/icons/Faenza
/usr/share/icons/ubuntukylin-icon-theme
/usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme

================
xieerqi:
$ find /usr/share/icons -maxdepth 2 -type d -iname "*places*"  -printf "%h\n" | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}'                         
Humanity
ubuntu-mono-light
Deepin-2013
Faenza-Dark
ubuntu-mono-dark
Deepin-icons
Deepin-sapphire
Deepin
Humanity-Dark
Faenza
ubuntukylin-icon-theme
unity-icon-theme
```

Comment: This is very close, but alas I need for the output to only contain the directories that have "places" as the first subdirectory.

For example, your output contains "/usr/share/icons/Human/48x48/places" where "places" is a sub-subdirectory.

Thank you for your comment, friend.

Comment: @ovine can you provide an example of what you mean ?

Comment: Almost, kos. find /usr/share/icons/* -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname "*places*" works perfectly, now I just need to know how to pipe it to another command that will strip /usr/share/icons/ and places/, so the output will only be the folder names in question.

Comment: Added small update, please check if that's what you need

Comment: Thanks, Serg, that was exactly what I needed! You're awesome.